# How can one's yearly reputation be larger than their total reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

When looking at the reputation leagues for MSE we can see that Teresa Dietrich is ranked 25th when it comes to yearly reputation gain.

[image]

We also see that her reputation gain is bigger than her current reputation.

The first suspect in this case is of course caching. So to check that I went to see her current reputation on her profile. That matches what was listed in the league under total reputation. Another culprit could of course be caching of the total gain, so I went to check if she received any downvotes today. Her public reputation history shows no entries since December 2nd.

[image]

The last thing could of course be that she downvoted something. That scenario is also highly unlikely as she was last seen 18 hours ago according to her profile. That was *yesterday* in UTC time, so the script had since run at UTC midnight.

Are there any other possibilities or is this a genuine bug?

P.s. there are also other users with similar things (even larger differences), but I decided to use an SE employee as an example.